# Firebird 2.5 Removing Rows with Duplicate Fields

Tags: firebird

I am trying to removing duplicate values which, for some reason, was imported in a specific Table.
There is no Primary Key in this table.
There is 27797 unique records.

```
Select distinct txdate, plunumber from itemaudit
```

Give me the correct records, but only displays the txdate, plunumber of course.

If it was possible to select all the fields but only select the distinct of txdate,plunumber I could export the values, delete the duplicated ones and re-import.
Or if its possible to delete the distinct values from the entire table.

If you select the distinct of all fields the value is incorrect.

Comment: Before I answer, I need to know what row from the duplicates you want stay. Ex.: Supose there is this three rows (txdate,plunumber,anotherfield) as (1,1,1), (1,1,2) and (1,1,3). What row should remain? The first one (1,1,1)? The last one (1,1,3)? Any of them?

Answer (score 4):

To get all information on the duplicates, you simply need to query all information for the duplicate rows using a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, txdate, plunumber 
      FROM itemaudit 
      GROUP BY txdate, plunumber 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) a
INNER JOIN itemaudit b ON a.txdate = b.txdate AND a.plunumber = b.plunumber
```

Comment: Script did not work from the program sql editor itself, Ran from Database workbench but got over 120 000 records where there is only 57544 records including duplicates

Comment: @user2516423 I have updated the query to filter only duplicates (that was missing from my previous edit).

Comment: no column name specified for column number 1 in derived table A

Comment: I typed the SQL from my head, you just need to add an alias for `COUNT(*)`, see my edit

Comment: Ir runs through the script stills showing duplicates i get the following comment
PLAN JOIN (SORT (A ITEMAUDIT NATURAL), B INDEX (I_ITEMAUDIT_TXDATE))

Comment: @user2516423 Of course it shows duplicates, that is what you asked for: you wanted all information of the duplicate rows. Regarding the plan: you probably have enabled your database tool to also request the execution plan. It is just informational.

Comment: as stated in the question i only need the distinct values (unique) which is 27797 rows the duplicates must be thrown out

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand your problem. You might want to update your question and be more explicit in describing what you need and what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM itemaudit t1
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM itemaudit t2
WHERE t1.txdate = t2.txdate and t1.plunumber = t2.plunumber 
AND t1.RDB$DB_KEY < t2.RDB$DB_KEY
);
```

Comment: Hi Hugo, thanks for your answer. To make it more useful, it's a good idea to explain how and why your SQL solves the OP's original problem.